# SDL event handling not working

Tags: c, codeblocks, sdl-2

I'm currently learning SDL by reading Lazy foo tutorials. I'm using code blocks 13.12 on Linux. I'm unable to get event handling to work correctly.

I'm basically trying to display an image (which works great), but no matter how many times I click on the close button, it won't close

Code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Declaring the main window, the main surface and the image surface
SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *scrsurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface *imgSurface = NULL;
SDL_Event event;
int run = 1;

//The function where SDL will be initialized
int init();
//The function where the image will be loaded into memory
int loadImage();
//The function that will properly clean up and close SDL and the variables
int close();

//The main function
int main(void){
    if(init() == -1)
        printf("Init failed!!!");
    else{
        if(loadImage() == -1)
            printf("loadImage failed!!!");
        else{

            //Displaying the image

            while(run){
                //Event handling
               while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
                    switch(event.type){
                        case SDL_QUIT:
                            run = 0;
                            fprintf(stderr, "Run set to 0");
                            break;
                        default:
                            fprintf(stderr, "Unhandled event");
                         break;
                    }
                } 
                //Blitting nad updating
                SDL_BlitSurface(imgSurface, NULL, scrsurface, NULL);
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            }
        close();

        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int init(){
 if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    return -1;
 else{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_WINDOW", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 900, 900, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window == NULL)
        return -1;
    scrsurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

}
return 0;
}


int loadImage(){
    imgSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("Test.bmp");
    if(imgSurface == NULL)
        return -1;
    else{

    }
    return 0;
}

int close(){
    SDL_FreeSurface(imgSurface);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;

}
```

`

Comment: Also, the fprintf doesn't display anything on both stdout and stderr streams

Comment: It is generally a very bad idea to call your non-static function `close`, as it aliases with libc's `close(int)`, and Xlib/SDL would likely call your function when trying to close its file descriptors. It is likely the cause why you don't see anything printed, and maybe more.

Comment: Thank you dude, that worked! Hope you'd posted that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it requires thorough debugging to determine what exactly happens, your problem is very likely to be caused by aliasing of libc's `close` function and yours. `close` is very important call used by many libraries, including Xlib (which is called by SDL). E.g. `SDL_CreateWindow` calls `XOpenDisplay`/`XCloseDisplay` to test display capabilities, but `XCloseDisplay` calls `close` on its connection socket, and it will call your function instead. It's hard to say what will happen after that, but it is certainly not what was intended.

Workaround is either renaming function to something else (e.g. by giving it a prefix) or by declaring it `static` so its name wouldn't be exported. Note that static functions may only be used within single translation unit (i.e. if your .c file contains static function, you cannot easily use it from another .c file).

Linker doesn't report multiple definitions here because libc's close is a weak symbol (`nm -D /lib/libc.so.6 | egrep ' close$'` reports `W`).

Answer (score 1):

Try moving close(); right after the end of the while (run) loop and before the // Blitting nad updating.
Also, move SDL_BlitSurface(imgSurface, NULL, scrsurface, NULL);
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window); somewhere else, as it will run after your program stops running, and all code after that will also run when run is set to 0.

Comment: Actually, close() is right after the end of the while(run) loop, while the blitting and stuff are inside the loop so yeah...

Comment: try deleting window = null from the close function

Comment: What do you mean by "won't close"? When you hover over the window, is there a loading circle (I do not know how it works on linux, but does the window project an animation indicating that it is "loading"?) or does the window just not disappear after you click the Close button?

Comment: It simply doesn't disappear and neither do the fprintfs show up on the console, also, close() works just fine without a loop, so I doubt that's the problem

Comment: But you are able to click on the Close button, right? Try to add another input like SDL_KEYDOWN,